# PHP Get multiple data from mysql in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, geojson

I am trying to get multiple columns data in a array fromate form data base like for example

```
[{"id":"3","category":"Name","text":"text with some data","image":"http:\/\/examole.net\/folder\/images\/category1.jpg"},{"id":"4","category":"Name","text":"text with some data","image":"http:\/\/examole.net\/folder\/images\/category1.jpg"}]
```

using for each statement i am not able to do it as a json response

```
$response = array();
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='test'){
        $query="select * from exampledb where id='".$db->escape($_REQUEST['id'])."'";
        $num= $db->num_rows($query);          
        if($num)
        {
            $rows = $db->get_results($query);

            foreach($rows as $row1) { 

                $response['id'] = $row1['id'];
                $response['category'] = $row1['category'];
                $response['text'] = $row1['text'];
                $response['image'] = $row1['image'];
            }       
        }
        else{
            $response['message']='No user Found';
            $response['status']='fail';
        }

    }
```

Comment: `json_encode()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for the reply can you share me an example

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: @HK007 just the last columns data

Comment: there are 4 rows data that needs to be shown but i am getting only one last rows {"id":"4","category":"90","text":"4","image":"Test4"}

Comment: What database layer is this? Does it support prepared statements? That might be a lot safer than this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after your `else`

```
else{
            $response['message']='No user Found';
            $response['status']='fail';
        }

echo json_encode($response) //<---- here convert array to json text
```

[PHP json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

**UPDATE**

```
foreach($rows as $k=>$row1) { //add index $k to use an automatic autoincrement for the key
//and put it inside each fields
                $response[$k]['id'] = $row1['id'];
                $response[$k]['category'][] = $row1['category'];
                $response[$k]['text'] = $row1['text'];
                $response[$k]['image'] = $row1['image'];
            }
```

Comment: can you post the json response ?

Comment: {"id":"4","category":"90","text":"4","image":"Test4"}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077446/php-array-with-in-array-i-am-not-able-to-create