# Php array with in array i am not able to create

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get two array values within an array. I have two situations, one is done and the another one is not done. Within an array I am able to get a single array, but not able to achieve multiples, as mentioned in the below expected output.

```
[{"id":"3","category":"Name","text":"text with some data","image":"http:\/\/examole.net\/folder\/images\/category1.jpg"},{"id":"4","category":"Name","text":"text with some data","image":"http:\/\/examole.net\/folder\/images\/category1.jpg"}]
```

code with done and notdone query

```
$response = array();
$response2 = array();
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='test') {
    $query="select * from exampledb where id='".$db->escape($_REQUEST['id'])."' and workdone='done'";
    $num= $db->num_rows($query);          
    if($num) {
        $rows = $db->get_results($query);

        foreach($rows as $k=>$row1) { 
            $response[$k]['id'] = $row1['id'];
                $response[$k]['category'] = $row1['category'];
                $response[$k]['text'] = $row1['text'];
                $response[$k]['image'] = $row1['image'];
            }       
        } else{
            $response['message']='No user Found';
            $response['status']='fail';
        }

        $query="select * from exampledb where id='".$db->escape($_REQUEST['id'])."' and workdone='notdone'";
        $num= $db->num_rows($query);          
        if($num) {
            $rows = $db->get_results($query);
            foreach($rows as $k=>$row1) { 
                $response[$k]['id'] = $row1['id'];
                $response[$k]['category'] = $row1['category'];
                $response[$k]['text'] = $row1['text'];
                $response[$k]['image'] = $row1['image'];
            }       
        } else {
            $response['message']='No user Found';
            $response['status']='fail';
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
        echo json_encode($response2);
    }
}
```

expecting output

```
    [{Done:{{"id":"3","category":"Name","text":"text with some data","image":"http:\/\/examole.net\/folder\/images\/category1.jpg"},{"id":"4","category":"Name","text":"text with some data","image":"http:\/\/examole.net\/folder\/images\/category1.jpg"} }, 
    Notdone:{{"id":"3","category":"Name","text":"text with some data","image":"http:\/\/examole.net\/folder\/images\/category1.jpg"},{"id":"4","category":"Name","text":"text with some data","image":"http:\/\/examole.net\/folder\/images\/category1.jpg"}    }}]
```

Comment: You will not be able to achieve your expected output with `json_encode`, as it is not valid JSON.

Comment: thanks for the reply and what can be done to achive the same

Comment: Well, it's possible to get that output, but wouldn't you want to get something that _IS_ valid instead?

Comment: what is that i dint get you /s

Answer (score 0):

You can make this in two way

**1.**

Leave everything as is and move the `echo` just after the sql/array processing code:

```
//... [...] ...
}
        else{
            $response['message']='No user Found';
            $response['status']='fail';
        }

 echo json_encode($response); //<---- here for the first

$query="select * from exampledb where id='".$db->escape($_REQUEST['id'])."' and workdone='notdone'";
        $num= $db->num_rows($query);  //.......
```

and

```
//... [...] ...
}
        else{
            $response['message']='No user Found';
            $response['status']='fail'; 
        }
    echo json_encode($response); //<---- here for the second
//.......
```

**2**

change relative variables inside foearch after your SECOND query

```
// this remains the same from here
 $query="select * from exampledb where id='".$db->escape($_REQUEST['id'])."' and workdone='done'";
        $num= $db->num_rows($query);          
        if($num)
        {
            $rows = $db->get_results($query);

            foreach($rows as $k=>$row1) { 

                $response[$k]['id'] = $row1['id'];
                $response[$k]['category'] = $row1['category'];
                $response[$k]['text'] = $row1['text'];
                $response[$k]['image'] = $row1['image'];
            }       
        }
        else{
            $response['message']='No user Found';
            $response['status']='fail';
        }
// ----------------- to here

// and here ....
        $query="select * from exampledb where id='".$db->escape($_REQUEST['id'])."' and workdone='notdone'";
        $num= $db->num_rows($query);          
        if($num)
        {
            $rows = $db->get_results($query);

            foreach($rows as $k=>$row1) { 
                //... change this with $response2
                $response2[$k]['id'] = $row1['id'];
                $response2[$k]['category'] = $row1['category'];
                $response2[$k]['text'] = $row1['text'];
                $response2[$k]['image'] = $row1['image'];
            }       
        }
        else{
            //... and this
            $response2['message']='No user Found';
            $response2['status']='fail';
        }
// 
echo json_encode($response);
echo json_encode($response2);
```

If you don't populate `$response2` you never get at the end for `json_encode`